# How to store a parameterized stored procedure output into another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which takes two parameters (two years) to return all the student information during that period in a school. It returns 3 columns i.e BirthYear, Name, Age. I have to store that procedure's output into another table which is holding the same structure. So the table will hold the structure as

```
BirthYear Name    Age 
---------------------
1988      Joshep  26
2000      John    17
```

and so on.

Now my procedure is called `getAllInfoOfStudent` and it takes two parameters which are any two years, `getAllInfoOfStudent (1900, 2018)` like that .

So my question is how will I get this done? Please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the table has that same structure, and the sp returns just that data, then you need to use `INSERT INTO`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
EXEC getAllInfoOfStudent (1900,2018);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same logic as you would use to insert into a table from a select statement as long as you have our output from your stored procedure formatted correctly to insert into your table.

```
INSERT INTO YourTableName    
    EXEC getAllInfoOfStudent 1990, 2018
```